# JOOQ get Columns from a Table

Tags: java, sql, h2, jooq

i try to get all `Columns` of a `Table` with `JOOQ` from a `H2` database (for testing - later it might be something like `MySQL` or `PostGRE`)

all is fine, but when i loop through my retrieved `Columns` and log the results to console i noticed a Problem (probably a BUG?)

my log code looks like this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d > [%s].[%s].[%s]", col.getOrdinalPosition(), col.getTableCatalog(), col.getTableName(), col.getColumnName()));
```

and the Output of my Table is this:

```
0 > [TEST].[PERSON].[PERSON]
1 > [TEST].[PERSON].[PERSON]
2 > [TEST].[PERSON].[PERSON]
```

i expected it to be:

```
0 > [TEST].[PERSON].[ID]
1 > [TEST].[PERSON].[FIRSTNAME]
2 > [TEST].[PERSON].[LASTNAME]
```

as the create script for the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
   ID         INTEGER        NOT NULL,
   FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR(255),
   LASTNAME   VARCHAR(255)
);

ALTER TABLE PERSON
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

so finally my question is: how do i get the 'real' Column-Name?

EDIT: tried using `JOOQ` version 3.9.0 and 3.9.1

UPDATE:
I found another way to retrieve the Column-Names:

if you already have the instance of `Table<?>` you can use this code to 'fix' the bug

```
// ordinal position starts at 1 but the fields-array starts at 0!
Field<?> f = tbl.fields()[col.getOrdinalPosition() - 1];
// this is needed due a bug in JOOQ, where the ColumnName is returned incorrect
col.setColumnName(f.getName());
```

Question: Where does Column come from?
Answer:

```
DSLContext dslCtx = DSL.using(cfg);
InformationSchema is = dslCtx.informationSchema(tbl);
List<Column> columns = is.getColumns();
```

the Class `Column` is out of `JOOQ`'s `org.jooq.util.xml.jaxb.Column`package;

Comment: @LukasEder i added the answer to your question to my original question; its coming from `JOOQ`'s package `org.jooq.util.xml.jaxb.Column`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, thanks for clarifying. Will answer, soon

Comment: Forgot to say: Thanks for reporting this issue, btw!

Comment: no problem, thanks for the fast reply & upcoming fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in jOOQ 3.9.1 and will be fixed in 3.10.0 and 3.9.2:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5812